# Google colab saving python code file in a desired folder on one drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google colab saves the working .ipynb file automatically to a folder under `Colab notebook`. Instead, I want to save this to the desired folder on the one drive where I have all the data files related to this python file. How to do this?

[image]